# Inappbrowser skype call

Tags: cordova, skype, inappbrowser

I have a mobile app that opens a website by cordova inappbrowser plugin. There is a skype call icon inside inappbrowser iframe (an 'a' element with href "skype:skype_name?call') that doesn't work in android device (tried on versions 6 and 7) but works on mobile browser (didn't try on iOS). The error is:

net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

I've tried so many things, I even deleted the witelist plugin.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?])(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: Does it work on iOS?

Comment: Also what Android OS version do you have?